# Can't reference a child with a variable instance name [syntax]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, instance

I want to generate villagers for my game and then organize them into a list but I'm having a bit of difficulty, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjdvz.png) is what it's supposed to look like and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QWGx.png) is what it actually looks like. The code for generating kinsmen is:

```
var k = new kinsmen  ;
menuArea.kinsmenDivider.addChild(k);
totalKinsmen++;
totalKinsmenAlive++;
k.name = "kinsmen" + totalKinsmen;
```

The code used for sorting them is:

```
for (var i:int = 1; i < (totalKinsmen+1); i++) {
if (menuArea.kinsmenDivider.getChildByName("kinsmen"+i) !=null) {
    menuArea.kinsmenDivider["kinsmen" + i].y = menuItemCount * 107.5;
    menuItemCount++;}}
```

That should look through the ID's of every kinsmen that's ever existed and when it finds the ID of one that's alive it should give it a place in the menu and continue going through the other IDs.

```
trace ("kinsmen" + totalKinsmen);
trace (menuArea.kinsmenDivider.getChildByName("kinsmen"+i));
```

Both always have the same values in my tests. The debugger posts the following error during runtime:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
```

When I remove ["kinsmen" + i] it stops giving errors and the entire menu moves down each time a new kinsmen is generated so I know that's the part causing the issue but I don't know why or how to fix it and would appreciate help, all the above code is in my document class. I only started coding AS3 a few days ago so I'm still a bit shaky. Cheers for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the clip correctly everywhere except

```
menuArea.kinsmenDivider["kinsmen" + i].y
```

shouldn't it be :

```
menuArea.kinsmenDivider.getChildByName("kinsmen" + i).y
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you ever so much. I didn't think of that one.

Comment: Do remember to mark the green tick next to this answer if it solved your problem.